# How to specify the icon for a dialog in After Effects?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, after-effects

The following script shows a simple dialog window in Adobe After Effects:

```
var window = new Window('dialog');
window.add('statictext', undefined, 'Hello world!');
window.show();
```

The resulting window has a rather unattractive default icon:

[image]

How do I change the dialog icon?

I tried setting the window's `image` property, the way it works for `IconButton`s, but that had no effect. I couldn't find any mention in the documentation, either.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Take a look into Peter Kahrels Script UI Guide http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html

Comment: You can create palette instead of 'dialog': new Window('palette'). Palette window should be displayed without any ugly icon (but it depends on the os and target application(after effect, illustrator..)

Comment: @emax: Thanks, but I'm explicitly going for the modal behavior of a dialog.

Comment: @fabianmoronzirfas: I'm already using that. But it doesn't cover that aspect. As a matter of fact, none of the dialog screenshots in there contain an icon. So it seems to be just one more After Effects scripting problem that's version-dependent. :-(